# Hiding div if string contains specific text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to hide 2 separate divs based on the contents of the second one (ie, if the P contains the word "None").

```
<div class="fusion-text fusion-text-9 fusion-text-no-margin" style="color:#000000;margin-bottom:5px;">
  <p><strong>Twitter :</strong></p>
</div>
<div class="fusion-text fusion-text-10" style="margin-right:60px;" id="twitter-handle">
  <p>None</p>
</div>
```

I'm able to hide the div with the ID of twitter-handle by using the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#twitter-handle p:contains('None')").parent('div').hide();
});
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to **also** hide the first div, with the class "fusion-text-9" (it's unique on the page).

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: `$("#twitter-handle p:contains('None')").length` tells you if this finds anything, so wrap it into an `if`, and inside hide `.fusion-text-9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`prev`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) method should be what your looking for...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $found = $("#twitter-handle p:contains('None')").parent('div');
    $found.hide();
    $found.prev().hide();
});
```

You can also pass a selector to the `prev` method...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $found = $("#twitter-handle p:contains('None')").parent('div');
    $found.hide();
    $found.prev('.fusion-text-9').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a vanilla JS solution instead of using jQuery you can use the `match()` method on the element's text content:

```js
let fusionText = document.querySelectorAll(".fusion-text");

fusionText.forEach(element => {
  if (element.textContent.match(/None/)) {
     fusionText.forEach(element => {
         element.style.display = "none";
     })
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="fusion-text fusion-text-9 fusion-text-no-margin" style="color:#000000;margin-bottom:5px;">
  <p><strong>Twitter :</strong></p>
</div>
<div class="fusion-text fusion-text-10" style="margin-right:60px;" id="twitter-handle">
  <p>None</p>
</div>
```

**further reading**

More here about [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [textContent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Comment: Slightly misunderstood the question - to remove both elements, the code is now amended

Answer (score 2):

to also hide the first div, with the class "fusion-text-9"...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#twitter-handle p:contains('None')").parent().parent().hide();
});
```

```html
<div class="fusion-text fusion-text-9 fusion-text-no-margin" style="color:#000000;margin-bottom:5px;">
  <p><strong>Twitter :</strong></p>
</div>
<div class="fusion-text fusion-text-10" style="margin-right:60px;" id="twitter-handle">
  <p>None</p>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a demo to show how to deal with the found elements and addressing the parent before hiding it (according to the selector criteria):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   const psToHide = $("#twitter-handle p:contains('None')");   
   psToHide.each((i, o)=>{        
      $(o).closest('div').hide();
   });   
});
```

```css
.extraDivForTheSakeOfBorderAndShowingScaling{
  border: solid red 1px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="extraDivForTheSakeOfBorderAndShowingScaling">
  <div class="fusion-text fusion-text-9 fusion-text-no-margin" style="color:#000000;margin-bottom:5px;">
    <p><strong>Twitter :</strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="fusion-text fusion-text-10" style="margin-right:60px;" id="twitter-handle">
    <p>Containing None</p>
    <p>Not containing</p>
    <p>Not containing</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div  class="extraDivForTheSakeOfBorderAndShowingScaling">
  <div class="fusion-text fusion-text-9 fusion-text-no-margin" style="color:#000000;margin-bottom:5px;">
    <p><strong>Facebook (and so on..) :</strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="fusion-text fusion-text-10" style="margin-right:60px;" id="twitter-handle">
    <p>Containing None</p>
    <p>Not containing</p>
    <p>Not containing</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make both of them disappear you need to find a common ground.

If your neighbour-div you want to hide allways is next to the div, that contains 'None', then you can simply extend your jQuery by:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#twitter-handle p:contains('None')").parent('div').hide();
 $("#twitter-handle p:contains('None')").parent('div').previousElementSibling.hide();
});
```

If the other component ist further away inside another div on the other side of the dom-tree, id suggest to give them both the same styleclass. Your code could then look something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 let nonePTag = $("#twitter-handle p:contains('None')")
 nonePTag.parent('div').hide();
 $(nonePTag.classList[0]+" p:not(:contains('None'))")
});
NOTE: The common class has to be in the index (in my exsample the first) position of all classes.
```

I hope i could help you